# How can I add Cross 'X' Icon in angucomplete-alt plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm using [Angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) for showing my autocomplete result. I want to add one 'X' Cross icon inside text box that will clear the text entered in the text box as per below image.

[image: textbox with cross mark icon]

I tried So many angular directives ([angular-input-clear-icon](https://github.com/aseemgautam/angular-input-clear-icon)) and jquery plugins but nothing is working along with angucomplete-alt plugin.
Any Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/autocomplete see this url hope this is help full.

Comment: You can clear the data of input field using `ng-click` function.

Comment: I need that cross mark inside textbox.

Comment: You can place it using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
scope.inputType = attrs.type ? attrs.type : 'text';
```

To

```
scope.inputType = attrs.type ? attrs.type : 'search';
```

Also add this line in clearResults() method

```
if (scope.selectedObject && scope.selectedObject.originalObject)
                scope.selectedObject.originalObject = {};
```